# How to integrate my Spring boot, angular application with YubiKey Enterprise edition

Tags: angular, spring-boot, yubikey

Front-end i am using Angular and back-end i am using Spring boot and microservices architecture.
I got the YubiKey API from the following source.

```
https://console.yubico.com/apidocs/#operation/CreateShipmentExact.
```

In my angular application I have different screen, after going through APIs details from the above link, I realized that some of the APIs I can use directly from YoubiKey but some of them I have to create so in my microservice I am designing the APIs.

the problem is I am not able to test the APIs. while doing so, I am getting unauthorized 401 error because each API expecting the API key in the HTTP header.
I found that I need to contact the sales team from YubiKey in order to get the API key. I referred the following link.

```
https://github.com/YubicoLabs/yed-self-service
```

so, when I am using the above link, I found the link where I can connect with the sales team.

https://www.yubico.com/contact-us/

here I am filling my basic details and after submitting I am getting the message as
**Someone will be reaching you out to contact you shortly.**

but nobody reaching me out.
can someone please provide the details about this integration. and at least where I should start from.

Comment: I think this will help you to move forward. All the best. 
https://developers.yubico.com/Software_Projects/

Comment: hi pawan, it is mentioned on the link that the project is deprecated. and i am looking how to get the API token.